# Method of extracting data from a website?

Tags: java, web-services, http, curl, web-scraping

I want to grab data from a website (for example, the names, identification number, and list of resources someone is using) and post it to another website.

What I was thinking of doing was using cURL to grab the information from an existing REST api on one website. Then, what I wanted to do is write a program or an api to post that information onto another website.

Upon using a cURL, how/where can I store that information so that I can use it via another program? Would it be easier to write one single program that extracts the information from the first website and posts it to the other? If so would it be possible to do so using Java/give an idea on how to do so? I'm not asking for code, just a method to do this. I'm using the Eclipse for Java Web EE developer's IDE.

Comment: Your IDE makes no difference. curl or use `URLConnection` to extract the data, write it to a text file, then read it and do what you want. There are tutorials and question/answers about each step of your problem all over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it as 2-3 programs.  One that extracts the data, one that formats the data (if necessary), one that posts the data.

My gut tells me the easiest way to do this is a pure bash script.  But if you want to use Java for this you can.

I would save the output in a file for the post-er to read from.  This has the benefit of letting you write/test the poster without the 2 other programs working.  That said, I recommend you write the get-er program first.  That way you know what data you're really dealing with.

Now, if you happen to write both the formatter and the post-er in java, I would write this as one program instead of "piping" files between them.  The formatter will read in the file, turn it into a data structure/class, and the post-er will read this data structure/class.

This is only superficially different from my previous paragraph.  The point is each "part" is independent from each other.  This allows you to test a part without running the whole thing.  That's the important thing.

As for how/where to store the information from the get-er, just redirect it to a file.  [Here's a tutorial on how.](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/iodirection.html)

Truth be told, I can't tell if you're using the linux cURL program or a [java implementation like this one](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/).  My answer would be very different depending on this.